# Personal pronouns in genitive case?

Tags: местоимения

I noticed that the accusative case is:
•Меня→Me
•Тебя→You (informal, singular)
•Его/Него→Him, it (M)
•Её/Неё→Her, it (F)
•Его/Него→It(N)
•Нас→Us
•Вас→You (formal, plural)
•Их/Них→Them

But I also noticed that the genitive case goes exactly the same, but I'd like to know what the **equivalent** is. As you can see the equivalents in the accusative case are me, you, him, her, it, us, you and them. Basically, can someone translate the personal pronouns in genitive case to English? Please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

English doesn't have cases anymore, him/her/me/them/us is just a remnant of a case system that got abolished long ago, so "translating" the cases to English doesn't really make sense. Don't think about what some Russian case would be in English. You should instead think about the class of questions the cases answer in Russian and try to memorize the declensions.

In Russian, the accusative case answers the questions *Кого?/Что?* and the genitive case answers *Кого?/Чего?*.

For accusative it would be something like *Кого ты видел? Его, её, Кол**ю***

In Engish, it's just *Who did you see? Him, her, Kolya*

For genitive, *Кого нету дома? Его, её, Кол**и***

*Who isn't home? He, she, Kolya*

Answer (score 0):

Prepositions which govern genitive case in Russian are у, около, возле, вокруг (near, around), от (from), до (to, till), без (without).  For all these prepositions, the English pronoun is him/her/me/them/us.

Negations like "здесь его нет" are hard to translate to English without rearrangning words, but similar rearrangement would change case in Russian. "There is no him here" sounds odd, and "He is not here" is equivalent to the Russian "Он не здесь", in which sentence the pronoun is in nominative.

Disclaimer: there are many possible translations for each preposition, depending on the context. I give what I consider to be the most common translation. Also, it is possible that I forgot some preposition/s which govern the genitive.